# Dynamically adding onchange function to drop down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a couple of drop down boxes with ids country1, country2, ... When the country is changed in a drop down the value of the country shoudl be displayed in an alert box.

if I add the onchange handler for one box like this it works fine:

```
 $('#country1') .live('change', function(e){
        var selectedCountry = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(selectedCountry);
 });
```

But I need to do this dynamically for all drop down boxes so I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=country]') .each(function(key,element){
    $(this).live('change', function(e){
      var selectedCountry = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
      alert(selectedCountry);
     });
  });               
});
```

This doesn't work. No syntax error but just nothing happens when the seleted country is changed. I am sure that the each loop is performed a couple of times and the array contains the select boxes.

Any idea on that?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: The .live() method has been deprecated. Use .on() instead.

Comment: @MaggiQall: The Id is unique id^=country means it starts with country

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of incremental ids I'd use a class. Then the `live` method is deprecated but you may use `on` with delegation on the closest static parent or on `document` otherwise.

```
$('#closestStaticParent').on('change', '.country', function() {
  // this applies to all current and future .country elements
});
```

You don't need an each loop this way; plus events are attached to *all* the elements in the jQuery collection, in this case all `.country` elements.

Comment: The on method is available since jQuery 1.7 as far as I know but I am stuck with jQuery 1.6 at the moment

Comment: Then you can still use `live` but with a class, like `$('.country').live(...)`. That would be the equivalent of doing `$(document).on('event', '.country')` on jQ 1.7+

Comment: You can still use event delegation in 1.6, you just have to test the target against your selector yourself. `$("#closestStaticParent").change(function(e){ if ($(e.target).is(".country")) // do something });`

Comment: @elclanrs: Great, that worked. Still wondering why my code did not work but your solution is ways more readable anyway. Thanks a million...

Answer (score 6):

The reason `.live()` existed was to account for elements not present when you call the selector.

`$('[id^=country]') .each(function(key,element){` iterates over elements that have an `id` that starts with `country`, but *only those that exist when you run the selector*. It won't work for elements that you create after you call `.each()`, so using `.live()` wouldn't do you much good.

Use the new style event delegation syntax with that selector and it should work:

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^=country]', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

Replace `document` with the closest parent that doesn't get dynamically generated.

Also, consider adding a class to those elements along with the `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, the on method is available since jQuery 1.7 as far as I know but I am stuck with jQuery 1.6 at the moment. The elements do exist when I run the selector, they are not dynamically created. It is just the onchnage functionality that is created dynamically

Comment: @Paul: I'm not sure what you mean by *onchnage functionality that is created dynamically*.

Comment: this saved my life... spent two hours trying to figure out how to select from my dyn dropdown and populate another close dd and this function worked perfectly U ROCK!